# Incomplete output from Python command in a Bash script

Tags: shell-script, python

It is my first post here.

I am creating a simple `bash` script which should run a `python` command and mail the output. However, every time the script is running via `cron`, half of the `python` output is missing. Whereas, if I run the same script manually on shell, everything works as expected.

The bash script is:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

echo $(/usr/local/bin/python3 /home/tech2/myscript_v3_4-3.py -rs) > /home/tech2/weeklyreportoutput.txt

sleep 180

echo "Data Generated on $(date +%T_%d_%m_%y)" | mail -s "Data for Weekly SYNC $(date +%A_%F_%T)" -a /home/tech2/weeklyreportoutput.txt tech2@example.com
```

Note: The `python` script runs max for 10 seconds and output is not more than 100 lines. I have also tried without `echo`, but in that case `python` doesn't run with `-rs` argument.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your question to include examples of how the output should look like (and does, if you run the script by hand), and how it looks when run from `cron`. Also, it is unusual for a `bash` script to start with `#!/usr/local/bin/python3`...

Comment: Thanks for replying guys!

If I run it without echo, the python command doesn't take -rs argument. This argument/switch is necessary to get desired reports.
I also tried to replacing #!/usr/local/bin/python3 with #!/bin/sh, no changes in the behavior of the script.

Comment: The way it is now, your bash script will be run with the python interpreter (unless you start it like `bash myscript.sh`). This is wrong. You should either use `#!/bin/sh` for a `sh` script and `#!/bin/bash` for a `bash` script.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you run the python program, capture the output, then echo the (unquoted) output? Just do

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 /home/tech2/myscript_v3_4-3.py -rs > /home/tech2/weeklyreportoutput.txt
```

One of the main problems with your approach is that newlines will replaced by spaces.